# Согласование и пунктуация, - верен ли мой вариант?

Tags: пунктуация

> Сад предлагает завораживающие перспективы. В том числе несколько
>   обзорных точек на одну из знаменитых ротонд мира, редкой по типологии
>   – круглой христианской церкви.

Правильно ли будет так:

> Сад предлагает завораживающие перспективы. В том числе несколько
>   обзорных точек на одну из знаменитых ротонд мира – редкую по типологии
>   круглую христианскую церковь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложение, начатое с присоединительного союза "в том числе" получается без сказуемого - лучше поставить перед "в" запятую и объединить с первым. Либо можно начать второе с "в **их** числе" (правда, получится явное обращение к абстрактным, но штучным "перспективам"). В остальном - всё нормально.

Comment: Саш, дроблёный текст - прерогатива автора! Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: _Alex_ander: ...В остальном - всё нормально._ === **???...** Не знаю, сколькими вопросительными знаками передать своё недоумение...

Comment: Вы хотели бы запятую после "топологии" поставить?